# Good resources that talk about geodesically convex sets for riemannian manifolds?

Tags: manifolds, riemannian-geometry, geodesic, convex-hulls

Are there any good resources that talk about geodesically convex sets, and in particular convex hulls, for riemannian manifolds? I’ve been wanting to learn more about them, their geometry and properties, theorems about them, etc. I’m suprised to see I can’t find much resources on them, but maybe I’m not looking in the right places. I’ve found a few good ones though, like [this](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2011-139-02/S0002-9939-2010-10541-5/S0002-9939-2010-10541-5.pdf), but I can’t find much discussion about them beyond giving a general definition.

I also want to emphasize that I am not looking for the convex hull in the ambient space, but within the manifold.

Comment: I suggest posting this on MathOverflow. Such sets are not easy to study, so I consider this a research level question.

Comment: @Deane Okay, I made an identical question there. Interesting you said they are not easy to study. Even geodesically convex hulls?

Comment: Curvature can twist things up a lot.

Comment: Do you have a specific question in mind? In this degree of generality (without assuming, say, that you are working with Hadamard manifolds), it's hard to say anything about convex subsets and convex hulls. The only general result out there is the existence of totally convex neighborhoods.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I am in particular looking for convex sets on matrix Lie groups $G$ equipped with the Riemannian metric $\langle u,v\rangle_g = \frac{1}{2} tr((g^{-1}u)^T (g^{-1}v))$ for $g \in G$ and $u,v \in T_gG$.

Comment: Killing metrics are typically non-Riemannian (unless you assume compactness and semisimplicity of your Lie group). But what do you want to know about these convex subsets besides definition?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Sorry I think I misused the term. I re-write my response to you with the correct Riemannian metric.

Comment: @MoisheKohan As you can see from my question, I want to know anything. I suppose I want to know more about how to determine whether a point is in the interior, boundary, or outside a convex hull. In Euclidean space, there are many methods to determine this, like convex combinations and whatnot. I found this one paper I linked to in my post, yet it doesn't explain enough.

Comment: I see. Then, even for compact Lie groups there are no general methods for solving such problems unless you are considering "small" subsets (i.e. ones contained in totally convex neighborhoods). You may ask at Mathoverflow, but, I think, you will get the same answer. All the known general methods work only under the assumption that curvature is $\le 0$ which will not happen in your situation (unless you are dealing with a commutative Lie group).

Comment: @MoisheKohan That's crazy. How is there no mathematical research dedicated to studying something as practical as convex sets in compact Lie groups?

Comment: @SpencerKraisler Because convexity in this setting is not a very good notion.

Comment: @MoisheKohan What do you think is a better notion for studying more global properties on manifolds? I would think convex sets are the key.